# Разделение поля по строкам и столбикам

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Имеется поле крестиков-ноликов 3х3
Я хотел бы сделать разделение столбиков и строк как в оригинальной игре.
Пробовал делать `border-left: 2px solid white;`
Но это все не то

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
.head {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.kopole {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin: 83px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.kopole button {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 5px 3.4px;
    background-color: #2e2e3060;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80px 80px;
}
.kopole button:focus {
    background-color: #29292980;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="kopole">
    <button id="0 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="0 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="0 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил `::before`, `::after` к кнопкам, но я б переделал кнопки `div` и к ним добавил класс

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
.head {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.kopole {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin: 83px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.kopole button {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 5px 3.4px;
    background-color: #2e2e3060;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 80px 80px;
    position:relative;
}
.kopole button::before{
    content: '';
    width: 3px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -8px;
}
.kopole button::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -3px;
}
.kopole button:nth-child(3n)::before, .kopole button:nth-child(7)::after, .kopole button:nth-child(8)::after, .kopole button:nth-child(9)::after{
   background: transparent;
}
.kopole button:focus {
    background-color: #29292980;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="kopole">
    <button id="0 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="0 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="0 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="1 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 0" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 1" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
    <button id="2 2" onclick=setKo(this)></button>
</div>
</body>
```